# nginx 413 request entity too large when up[loading more than 1Mb file

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to post a file bigger than 1 mb and i get this Nginx error.
I have changed client_max_body_size 500M in nginx.conf and post_max_size=500M
upload_max_filesize=500M in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Try restart/reload both nginx and PHP to load the new configuration.